# Is the PL/SQL function dbms_lock.sleep Safe?

Tags: oracle, sleep

Is it going to tie up a CPU while it's "sleeping" or some other undesirable side affect?

Yes--paranoid, but working with some critical code and don't want any gotchas.

Comment: It will do an idle wait.  "Undesirable side affect" is a bit broad, though.  There is a fair amount of uncertainty about exactly when the thread will be awakened-- if you're sleeping for a couple hundredths of a second, for example, you might wake up a tenth of a second later.  Less of a concern if you're sleeping for multiple seconds.

Comment: In my case precision isn't important. I'm dealing with a situation where one system is overloading another system causing it to crash. I'm looking for a way to gracefully "throttle" how much is being thrown at the target system. Sleep seemed to be the ideal way to do it.

Comment: That may be perfectly reasonable.  Depending on the scope of the issue, you may want an asynchronous queue that one process can enqueue messages into and another process (or processes) can dequeue later.  That way, the consumer process(es) can take care of throttling themselves rather than needing the producer know enough to know how to throttle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP` does not consume any important resources and is perfectly safe to use.

I've used it many times and never experienced any problems.  The below test creates a massive amount of sleeping jobs but does not cause any problems.

---

To test the `SLEEP` function, create a huge amount of jobs that all sleep at the same time.

First, make sure that the database can support a large number of jobs.  There are several parameters that may limit this.  Check the below parameters:

```
select name, value
from v$parameter
where name in ('job_queue_processes', 'processes', 'sessions')
```

Create 1000 scheduled jobs that wait 30 seconds.

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        dbms_scheduler.create_job(
            job_name => 'JOB_'||i,
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            start_date => systimestamp,
            enabled => true,
            job_action => 'begin dbms_lock.sleep(30); end;'
        );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Now see how many jobs are running:

```
select count(*) from gv$session where schemaname = user;
select count(*) from dba_scheduler_running_jobs where owner = user;
```

On my desktop I only get 239 jobs.  It's not 1000 because of the original parameters, but I would consider 239 to still be a good "large" value.

Even with all that activity I don't notice any performance issues and Oracle uses less than 1% of the CPU.

Comment: very good answer. Only thing, there should no transaction or locks prior to the sleep that may block stuff.